# C++ Design Problem Regarding Templating, Containers and Inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, types

I have a problem with my design regarding interfacing algorithmic classes I have written and a third-party API. I will write some pseudocode to help explain my problem. I would prefer not to involve `boost` if possible.

**The Problem**

I have an algorithm class I will call `Alg` (it can be thought of as a search/optimisation algorithm) and a "super" algorithm class I will call `SuperAlg` which holds a number of `Alg` objects in a `std::vector<Alg>`. The `SuperAlg` evaluation function relies on a third-party algorithm, and thus needs to convert the result of any number of these `Alg` class objects into a third-party type. Each `Alg` may be associated with a different third-party type, which is known at the construction-time of the `Alg` class objects. The `SuperAlg` evaluation function looks something like:

```
double SuperAlg::evaluate(const std::vector<AlgResultType>& input) {
    ThirdPartyValues values;
    for (const auto& i : input) {
        values.insert(convert(i));
    }
    ThirdPartyAlg alg;
    return alg.error(values);
}
```

Here:

- the `ThirdPartyValues::insert` is a templated function in the third-party API that knows how to take many different third-party types
- `ThirdPartyAlg::error` takes a `ThirdPartyValues` and returns a `double`.
- `input` is a vector of all the results from the `Alg` searches, with a 1-to-1 correspondence with the `std::vector<Alg>` owned by the `SuperAlg` class.

There are a lot of these third-party types and let's say that if I know the type and have the result of an `Alg` search (`AlgResultType`), I know how to perform the conversion. i.e. The `convert` function is known:

```
ThirdPartyType convert<ThirdPartyType>(const AlgResultType& result);
```

The fundamental problem is this: *How can I specify the type of `i` I need to convert to in `SuperAlg::evaluate`? Recall that this type is known at the construction time of each `Alg` and somehow needs to be retained.*

**Some Solution Thoughts**

- If `Alg`/`AlgResultType` are templated with `ThirdPartyType` and the `convert<ThirdPartyType>` function is exposed through their interface, then they cannot be held in a dynamic-sized homogeneous containers and c++ doesn't have a dynamic-sized heterogenous container type.
- Often the way around holding many different types (e.g. due to their template), `Alg<ThirdPartyType>`/`AlgResultType<ThirdPartyType>` in this case, is to have a common base class and have `std::vector` hold this base class, however this base class would need to have the `convert<ThirdPartyType>` function in order to be useful in `SuperAlg::evaluate`, which relies on the template parameter.
- Some sort of container of types whereby each `Alg` or `AlgResultType` could be associated with a `ThirdPartyType`, but I know of no such container.

**Edit**

Thanks @Evg for pointing me towards `std::variant` and `std::visit`. I now have a working, although not very elegant solution but holding a `std::vector<std::variant<Alg<ThirdPartyType1>, Alg<ThirdPartyType2>, ...>>` in `SuperAlg` and exposing the `ThirdPartyType convert(const AlgResultType& result)` function in the `Alg` class.

The ugly part about this solution is that to call any member function in `Alg` from within `SuperAlg`, I need to create a lambda function for that member function of `Alg` and then call it with `std::visit(lambda, alg_variant)`

Comment: Take a look at `std::variant` + `std::visit`.

Comment: thanks @Evg, I just happened to stumble up on that - might be just what I need

Comment: The normal OO way of doing this is having a vector of *pointers* to the common base class of all `Alg` objects. The latter should have at least one *virtual function*. Your (pseudo)code is a bit unclear since there is no `Alg` or `vector<Alg>` in it so please clarify what it actually does.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. there is a `vector<Alg>` as a member of `SuperAlg` as I explained, but as i note in my second dot point in "Some Solution Thoughts", a base class wouldn't be appropriate here as the virtual function that is needed is the convert function and templated functions can't be virtual.

Comment: It isn't at all clear why it would need to be a template, rather than call an instantiation of a template. Don't describe code, show it instead (even if it's not working). A [mcve] is in order.

Comment: Consider inverting it: `values.insert(convert(i));` becomes `i.convert_and_insert_into(values);`. Since ThirdPartyValues is a concrete type, you could make this virtual, and store a common base in the vector.

Comment: that's a good idea @JeffGarrett, I think that would work (and be much less confusing to read and extend compared to the visit/variant pattern). I'll try that out and see if I run into any problems